# Add top level mapping element when converting a json file to yaml

Tags: json, yaml, yq

I have the following `json` file:

```json
{
  "test1": {
      "POST": "{}",
      "GET": "{}"
  },
  "test2": {
      "HEAD": "{}",
      "GET": "{}"
  }
}
```

I can convert it to `yaml` as follows:

```
yq eval -P input.json --output-format=yaml
```

which gives me:

```yaml
test1:
  POST: '{}'
  GET: '{}'
test2:
  HEAD: '{}'
  GET: '{}'
```

Is there an elegant (`yq` - based way) of:

a) adding a top level mapping element (say named `config`) as in

```yaml
config:
  test1:
    POST: '{}'
    GET: '{}'
  test2:
    HEAD: '{}'
    GET: '{}'
```

b) removing the single quotes from `'{}'`?

I want my end result to be

```yaml
config:
  test1:
    POST: {}
    GET: {}
  test2:
    HEAD: {}
    GET: {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to your yq invocation.

- `{"config": .}` adds a wrapping field
- `.[][] |= fromjson` interprets any value two levels deep as JSON-encoded string.

Put together:

```bash
yq eval -P '{"config": (.[][] |= fromjson)}' input.json --output-format=yaml
```

```yaml
config:
  test1:
    POST: {}
    GET: {}
  test2:
    HEAD: {}
    GET: {}
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) v4.35.1

Note: Since v4.18.1, the `eval`/`e` command is the default, and can be omitted.